# How to modify those tuples in a list of tuples that contain specific value by given index

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples, say

```
a = [('foo', 3), ('bar', 1)]
```

and I want to modify the second element in the tuple containing `'foo'`. More specifically, I would like to increment that number. In other terms, I want to do

```
>>> increment(a, 'foo')
>>> print a
[('foo', 4), ('bar', 1)]
```

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary instead? Then you could just do `a['foo'] += 1`.

Comment: The content of a tuple can't be changed, although any mutable object within them can be. Unfortunately you want to change an integer value which is immutable type..so you'd have to replace the whole tuple at the desired index in the list.

Comment: @senshin Would you mind expanding on that idea?

Comment: I mean, if all you have is a list of 2-tuples, and you want to interact with them by reference to their 0th indices, this seems like exactly what you'd want to use a dictionary for - `a = {'foo': 3, 'bar': 1}`. Of course, this may not play nicely with the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly change a value *within* a tuple (tuples are immutable). However, you can replace the element with a new tuple that looks very much like the old one:

```
def increment(a, name):
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        if x[0] == name:
            a[i] = (x[0], x[1] + 1)
            break
```

Comment: by using `break` you assume that there's only one `foo` tuple, there're may be more that 1

Comment: @AlexanderStarostin: That's true. But the OP referred to *"the tuple"* implying that there is only one. Obviously, if there can be more than one, then remove the `break`.

Comment: Sure, thanks. I wasn't sure what the OP full requirements are, `break` brings some limitations that OP needs to be aware about :)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comments, you can't change the contents of a tuple in this case, so to answer the question posed in title of your question (and replace the entire tuple at that index, if any, found):

```
a = [('foo', 3), ('bar', 1)]

def find_index(name, seq):
    for i, tpl in enumerate(seq):
        if tpl[0] == name:
            return i
    return None

i = find_index('foo', a)
if i is not None:
    a[i] = a[i][0], a[i][1]+1

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[('foo', 4), ('bar', 1)]
```